# getResourcesAsStream can't load file from jUnit

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I've reached my wits' end trying to figure out why I can't load a file from my resources folder in a Gradle project.

My project has the following folder structure:

```
/src
    /main
        /java
            /datasets
                /IrisDataReader.java
        /resources
            /datasets
                /Iris.csv
    /test
        /java
        /resources
            /datasets
                /Iris.csv
```

In my test/java directory, I'm running some tests that use IrisDataReader to read Iris.csv into program.

The following produces a null pointer exception.

```
    InputStream inputStream = IrisDataReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/datasets/Iris.csv");
```

When built, Gradle creates the following file structure

```
/build
    /classes
        /main
            /datasets
                /IrisDataReader.class
    /resources
        /main
            /datasets
                /Iris.csv
```

Here's the strange part:
If I copy build/resources/main/datasets/Iris.csv into /build/classes/main/datasets/ , the class loader can load the file successfully. Any ideas?

I haven't changed any of the gradle default configurations or added any build tasks.

Comment: How are you running your code? What is the classpath?

Comment: I am running the JUnit with IntelliJ's gui. It is configured to use the module's classpath.(There are multiple modules in the project; the source tree above is one of the modules)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how IntelliJ's .iml files work, I noticed that my [module].iml file had a different module declared as it's external.root.project.path.

When I found it, it looked like:

```
external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/../anothermodule"
```

... So I changed it to this:

```
external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$"
```

When I cleaned and rebuilt the project, IntelliJ automagically edited it so that it looked like this:

```
external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.."
```

... And that seemed to do the job. Don't ask me.